# Editing Python Class in Shell and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, class, shell, sqlalchemy, edit

I'm working on in the terminal on a shell script following this tutorial http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html SQLAlchemy tutorial on Declare A Mapping. I needed to type in

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
>>> class User(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'users'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String)
        fullname = Column(String)
        password = Column(String)

        def __repr__(self):
            return "<\User(name='%s', fullname='%s', password='%s')>" % (
                self.name, self.fullname, self.password)
```

Issue is after I typed the password = Column(String) I hit enter twice and the .... changed to >>>. I then retyped everything back in but then an error was thrown because the class already exists... I'm not totally sure how to fix this. How do I open up that class in the shell script and edit it (add in the def repr)

The error thrown is below:

```
/Users/GaryPeters/TFsqlAlc001/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/clsregistry.py:160: SAWarning: This declarative base already contains a class with the same class name and module name as __main__.User, and will be replaced in the string-lookup table.
  existing.add_item(cls)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/Users/GaryPeters/TFsqlAlc001/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py", line 53, in __init__
    _as_declarative(cls, classname, cls.__dict__)

  File "/Users/GaryPeters/TFsqlAlc001/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 251, in _as_declarative
    **table_kw)

  File "/Users/GaryPeters/TFsqlAlc001/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 339, in __new__
    "existing Table object." % key)

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'users' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just close and reopen the shell, and type everything in again, this time making sure to hit <kbd>enter</kbd> only once, not twice.

Alternatively, make sure to add the indents whenever you encounter a blank line -- if you hit <kbd>enter</kbd> and then hit <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>space</kbd> the appropriate amount of times so you're indented to the right level, then you should be able to hit <kbd>enter</kbd> again without the shell ending your definition and displaying `>>>` again.

You should also be to redefine the class in the shell, so I'm not quite sure what you mean by "an error was thrown" -- it might be helpful if you were to edit your post to include the specific stack trace.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I ended up just going back and retyping everything like you said. I was hoping there was a better way than doing this?? What if I misspelled something when creating the class? Is there no way to go back and edit??

Comment: @Mazzone Hmm, the error looks more like a sql thing then a Python thing. Python doesn't have an issue with you redefining a class, but it looks like SqlAlchemy won't let you do that easily. I'm not entirely sure how SQLAlchemy works, so you may want to look into looking through their documentation to see if they address that problem. If you don't want to retype things again and again, you could try putting your code into a script (a `.py` file), and editing and rerunning that instead.